# Mushy sushi surimi texture?

Tags: sushi, japanese-cuisine

I've noticed a difference between most places when I go out for sushi compared to when I make it myself.

The crab sticks / surimi in maki rolls when I go out seem to have a much more mushy texture - however, I haven't found much information on what to do differently to achieve this.

Could it be that they chop it up and mix it with mayo or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of knead them a little with your hand.  Just roll them on the board to break up the "fibers"

Answer (score 1):

Since surimi is made of finely chopped fish reassembled and kept together (usually with additives), I suppose you can blend a few sticks and then recompose them, maybe adding a  natural thickener like egg or cornstarch.

Please note that crabmeat and surimi are very different, the first is actually crab while the latter is white-flesh fish shaped to resemble something else, e.g. a claw or a shrimp's tail.

By the way, my suggestion here is to use real raw fish, your sushi will taste great.

Comment: Using raw fish comes with a whole host of safety concerns that making veggie and cooked-fish sushi does not, first and foremost being the need to source your fish appropriately. For that reason, many people only eat raw-fish sushi that's been prepared by a professional even if they make their own sushi at home.

Comment: I usually do use raw fish in addition to surimi :-)

Comment: @Yamikuronue I wasn't aware of that. In Italy it is perfectly normal to buy and eat raw fish, of course while keeping in mind safety concerns about parasites and bacteria.
RasmusKL, that's a great suggestion to keep the bill low :)!

Comment: @m.bagattini Most fish sold in US and UK markets isn't sushi-grade, and thus can't be confirmed safe for raw consumption, like most other meats. For me, I'd have to mail-order flash-frozen fish, overnight delivery in a refrigerated container, from a sushi supply place online, which gets pricy.